# Sendgrid unhandled error which is persisting in newly created accounts

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, sendgrid

I have made a contact form where the user can send a message to the admin.
Use has to provide a message for which I have a text are and then he has to provide his email id and his name.
After clicking on sending the admin should receive a message.

I used SendGrid recent API and it does require some changes but I don't want to give a single sender manually.
I want anyone who comes to my site should be able to communicate with me via the contact form.

Probably, the normal contact form which we all know.

I checked in console log and it gives an error like

```
{
    errors: [{
        message: 'The from address does not match a verified Sender Identity. Mail cannot be sent until this error is resolved. Visit https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/sender-identity/ to see the Sender Identity
        requirements ',
        field: 'from',
        help: null
    }]
}
```

This tells that the user input value is not a verified address, I can use a single sender and make it work but I don't want such manual workings.
Instead, everybody should be able to contact me and I don't need to add them manually on my SendGrid.

Comment: Without any code or indication what you've tried you're not likely to get an answer, Dhiraj. You say you used an API: show how you called it at the very least.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes It does not require code as such its related to send grid.Please refrain asking about code because it is working fine using single sender feature in send grid.

Comment: I'm trying to help you ask good questions. The problem is that if you don't show what you've tried that the question is more considered a task than a real question and will likely be ignored or even downvoted. Feel free to ignore me otherwise.